# php mysql updating a row and sending a email with the updated information

Tags: php, mysql, email

I'm trying to update a row in a database, and sening the user an email with the updated information. when i seperate these two codes, they work fire. But combines they dont work.
Im generating a random number that will be updated into the database and ill send like i said the random number to the user itself.

```
<?php
    $kcr = mt_rand(10000,1000000);
        $to = $_GET['to'];

        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: <account@directofficesupport.com>' . "\r\n";

        $subject = "Uw account is successvol aangemaakt!";

        //begin body message
        $body = '<b><h4><font face="verdana">Bedankt voor uw registratie op DirectOfficeSupport.com, Uw account is successvol aangemaakt!</font></h4></b><p>';
        $body .= '<font face="verdana">Uw unieke verificatiecode: <b> '.$kcr.'</b><p>';



        //end body message
         $from = 'account@directofficesupport.com';
         (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) 



    <?php mysql_connect("localhost", "pp_12034_23", "BireBA82R5Nd") 
    or die("Connection Failed"); mysql_select_db("db_12034_23")or die("Connection Failed");



     $query = "UPDATE voskousers SET Kc = '$kcr' WHERE Email = '$to'"; if(mysql_query($query)){} else{ echo "fail";} 
             ?>
```

I get a white screen when i try these two codes combined.
I hope anyone has a solution.

Comment: You should look at your PHP error log. I suspect it will tell you that you're missing a `;` after your mail function, you are also re-opening your `<?php` tag without ever closing it on the mysql_connect, that can be removed

Answer (score 0):

You have some brackets/parentheses too many and a missing semi-colon in:

```
(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
^                                    ^^
```

change to

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 0):

Try with these corrections-

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
{
  echo "mail sent";
}
```

some changes in query-

```
$query = "UPDATE voskousers SET Kc = '".$kcr."' WHERE Email = '".$to."'";

 if(mysql_query($query)){ 
       echo "updation succesfull";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://webnaar.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/smtp-mailler-for-php/ 
Try this one it will work 100% 
also u can send the mail from local